# ToggleButton height not changing (beyond a minimum height) programmatically (Android)

Tags: android-togglebutton

I'm creating a button programmatically.

```
ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton(mContext, null, android.R.attr.borderlessButtonStyle);
```

I'm not able to change the height of the button below a minimum level. It does increase above a default level. However, it doesn't decrease. In case of adjusting width, i ain't facing any issues. Problem is only with respect to height. Any idea what can be wrong?

I've tried setmin height, setheight. However, it doesn't make any difference.